# FreeBSD dbmail , postfix port 110 error (220)

Tags: freebsd, email, postfix, smtp

I am currently setting up a FreeBSD mail server with DBMAIL and Postfix.
I have forwarded port 25,110 and 587 to this server. When I try to log in using pop3  on port 110 my mail program does not find the server. When O use port 25 or 578 for pop3, my mail program does find the server but gives error 220.

What could be wrong? I want to login on pop3 with port 110 but that is not working at all...

Comment: Update your question with what happens when you telnet to port 110 of the server? From the server itself and from the client machine.

Comment: then there is no reply

Comment: If you don't get anything from telnetting to server port 110 from the server, then your services are either not running or there is some firewall blocking. Restart the service, and look at the log if there are errors and disable the firewall (for now) to test.

Comment: Yesss you are right! The services was not added in /etc/rc.conf. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to add the service in `/etc/rc.conf`.
I added the following lines:

```
postfix_enable="YES"
dbmail_lmtpd_enable="YES"
dbmail_imapd_enable="YES"
dbmail_pop3d_enable="YES"
```

then I did restart dbmail and postfix...